# Giving multiple documents to a Java PrintService print job?

Tags: java, printing

I'm using the following method to print pdf documents to my printer.  It works fine if I want to print something just one time, but it takes much longer to print something multiple times.

```
public static void print() 
{
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, null);
    FileInputStream psStream = null;
    try 
    {
        psStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\My Documents\\document.txt");
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    if (psStream == null) 
        return;

    if (services.length > 0) 
    {
        PrintService myService = null;
        for (PrintService service : services) 
        {
            System.out.println(service.getName());
            if (service.getName().contains("printer_name")) 
            {
                myService = service;
                break;
            }
        }
        DocPrintJob printJob = myService.createPrintJob();
        Doc document = new SimpleDoc(psStream, flavor, null);

        try 
        {
            printJob.print(document, null);
        } catch (PrintException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } else 
    {
        System.out.println("No PDF printer available.");
    }
}
```

So if I want to print a document five times and I put `print()` in a loop, then there's a pretty long delay between each printing of the document.  This kind of makes sense to me because the connection to the printer has to be reestablished for each document, and the document has to be resent.  Is there any way to maybe give a print job the same document multiple times using this API?

I guess it's worth noting that I've tried putting the `printJob.print(document,null)` command in a loop which generated a `PrintException: already printing`.  Maybe if there was a way to make it wait until the current document is done before sending the next it could work?  At a loss here.  Thanks.

@mthmulders: I tried the following and only one copy printed.  Anything I did wrong?

```
    Doc document = new SimpleDoc(psStream, flavor, null);
    PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    set.add(new Copies(5));

    try 
    {
        printJob.print(document, set);
    } catch (PrintException e) 
    {   
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a document five times, I suppose you have to create a [`PrintRequestAttributeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttributeSet.html) and put a [`Copies`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/Copies.html) attribute in that with the number of copies you want to have.

Supply this `PrintRequestAttributeSet` as the second attribute to your `printJob.print(...)` call and it should be fine.

I cannot try it right now but following the Javadoc this seems the way to do it.

Comment: The Javadoc says "On many devices the supported number of collated copies will be limited by the number of physical output bins on the device, and may be different from the number of uncollated copies which can be supported." Don't know why, but maybe that explains?

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe if there was a way to make it wait until the current document is done before sending the next it could work?

I don't know if it would be the best way but if nothing else works, you can try adding a printJobListener :

```
printJob.addPrintJobListener(new MyPrintJobListener());
```

with the class MyPrintJobListenenr being :

```
public class MyPrintJobListener implements PrintJobListener{
    public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        System.out.println("printDataTransferCompleted");
    }

    public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        System.out.println("The print job was cancelled"); 
    }

    public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        System.out.println("The print job was completed"); 
    }

    public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        System.out.println("The print job has failed");
    }

    public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        System.out.println("No more events");
    }

    public void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        System.out.println("The print job require attention");
    }
}
```